# Cannot Validate dynamic content in Bootstrap modal pop up

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to validate dynamic content in my modal popup but the dynamic content which is added by button click on modal popup is not validating. As in the below working snippet there is a Add field button after clicking on the add field buton a field is added to the modal but the issue is that dynamically generated field is not getting validated.

```js
$(function() {
   $("#newModalForm").validate();
      $('.form-control').each(function() {
           $(this).rules("add", 
            {
                required: true,
                messages: {
                    required: "This field is required",
                }
            });
      }); 
      
      
       $(document).on('click', '#add_field', function (e) {
  $('#dynamic_div').html("<input type=text class=form-control>");
  });
  


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addMyModal">Open Modal</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="addMyModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Add Stuff</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form role="form" id="newModalForm">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3" for="email">A p Name:</label>
            <div class="col-md-9">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pName" name="pName" placeholder="Enter a p name"/>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3" for="email">Action:</label>
            <div class="col-md-9">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="action" name="action" placeholder="Enter and action">
            </div>
          </div>
          
           <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3" for="email">Dynamic field:</label>
            <div class="col-md-9" id="dynamic_div">
              
            </div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btnSaveIt">Save</button>
            <button type="button" id="add_field" class="btn btn-default">Add Field</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btnCloseIt" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a function to validate the new input added:

```js
$(function() {
    $("#newModalForm").validate();
    $('.form-control').each(function() {
        required($(this))
    });


    $(document).on('click', '#add_field', function(e) {
        $('#dynamic_div').html("<input type=text class=form-control>");
        required($(this))
    });

    function required(el) {
        el.rules("add", {
            required: true,
            messages: {
                required: "This field is required",
            }
        });
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addMyModal">Open Modal</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="addMyModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Add Stuff</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form role="form" id="newModalForm">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3" for="email">A p Name:</label>
            <div class="col-md-9">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pName" name="pName" placeholder="Enter a p name"/>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3" for="email">Action:</label>
            <div class="col-md-9">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="action" name="action" placeholder="Enter and action">
            </div>
          </div>
          
           <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3" for="email">Dynamic field:</label>
            <div class="col-md-9" id="dynamic_div">
              
            </div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btnSaveIt">Save</button>
            <button type="button" id="add_field" class="btn btn-default">Add Field</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btnCloseIt" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks can you please tell me why i'm getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of undefined after i called required($(this)) in my ajax success method like this success( function(html) {
 $('.divrow').html(html); required($(this))

Comment: I would need more information, ask a new question and maybe I can help you.